# Wordpress wp_nav_menu nav > a

Tags: php, wordpress, class, addition, nav

I'm actually working on a website and i develop a theme.

I've a problem with the wp_nav_menu.

I've a navigation like this :

```
<nav> 
   <a href="#">item 1</a>
   <a href="#">item 2</a>
   <a href="#">item 3</a>
   <a href="#">item 4</a>
</nav>
```

And i would like this menu:

```
<nav> 
   <a href="#" class="one columns">item 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="two columns">item 2</a>
   <a href="#" class="two columns">item 2</a>
   <a href="#" class="one columns">item 1</a>
</nav>
```

if you preferer , add a custom class for each . 
Here are the parameters of the current menu. No function in function.php

```
                    <?php
                        $menuParameters = array(
                          'theme_location' => 'primary',
                          'container'       => false,
                          'echo'            => false,
                          'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                          'depth'           => 0,
                        );

                        echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
                    ?>
```

Have u got any solution ?
I specify that the classes in the administration > navigation don't work

Comment: why doesn't work for the classes set in admin ?

Comment: I don't know .. Maybe the classes set work with <li> ..

Answer (score 0):

In your backend go to `Appearance -> Menus`. In the top right corner there is a tab called `Screen Options`, there in 'Show advanced menu properties' tick `CSS classes`, that will enable you to add adittional class to your menu items.

Comment: I specify that the classes in the administration > navigation don't work

Answer (score 0):

You need the [custom nav menu walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu) to achieve this.

First, you need to remove the `<ul>, </ul>, <li>, and </li>` tags on the walker,
and then move the css classes to the `<a>` tag.

Below is the walker i've tried, paste this on functions.php:

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {  
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}{$n}";
    }

    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "{$n}";
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );  

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';
        $atts['class']  = ! empty( $class_names )      ? $class_names      : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }


        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "{$n}";
    }
}
```

And set your wp_nav_menu args:

```
<?php
$menuParameters = array(
  'theme_location' => 'primary',
  'container'       => false,
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'walker'          => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu()
);

// no need to strip tags since the custom walker already trimmed it
echo wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters );
?>
```

Don't forget to set css class in the `Appearance -> Menus`